# Swing, reusing one "screen" for multiple runs

Tags: java, swing, jform

I have to develop a Java swing application which is supposed to perform a psychological experiment.

The experiment consists of a white screen in which appears a small emoticon, "stands there" for 3 seconds and then disappears. Then the screen is all white again and the person must click on the space he thinks the emoticon was. After that another emoticon appears in different space and the whole procedure is repeated multiple times. There will be a database for saving the original coordinates and the coordinates that the person clicked on.

My question is how this is going to happen in one window? I have tried with multiple JForms and it's way too much work, and it opens different windows for every iteration.

Comment: please read Oracle tutorials JLabel, Icon, MouseListener, Swing Timer, bunch of code examples here,

Comment: Please have a look at [Playing with Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/), by @camickr, it has some interesting things that you might need for your project, like bounds checking for shapes :-)

Answer (score 3):

Start with

- [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to write a mouse listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Start with something like a `JPanel`.  This is where you do all your work.  You can create an instance of a `JFrame` and add this component to it.

When the user is ready, you would start a cycle.  This would load the details from the database, start `javax.swing.Timer` and request that the component be repainted (so it can display the image)

When the timer triggers, it should reset the display (blank).

When the user clicks the component (which will be detected by the mouse listener), you can record the mouse point and start a new cycle.

Comment: +1 this will help the user in solving the problem as well as making him learn lot of stuffs

Answer (score 2):

Here's what to do. You need to create a class that extends `JPanel` and overrides `paintComponent` to paint the image in the appropriate place. The constructor should also add a mouse listener that can detect a mouse click in the appropriate area, update the data, and call `repaint()`. As for hiding the emoticon after a specified amount of time, use a swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Now, I'm not going to give an example, because we don't do your homework for you on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation:

Make your window a JPanel and override the paint method

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // do your painting here
    }
}
```

First make sure you wipe everything from the Jpanel (from the paint method)
Next in the paint method show up the emoticon image (search for java swing paint image...)
But only if the emoticon data is there (coordiantes).

Next make a function that wil toggle the emoticon coordinates

```
toggleEmoticon(){
 if(emoticon.x != -1 && emoticon.y != -1){
   emoticon.x=-1;
   emoticon.y=-1;
 }
 else{
   emoticon.x = random() //between 0 and panel width
   emoticon.y = random() //between 0 and panel height
 }
```

Make a timer that calls this function after x seconds...

Then you'll have to check if the mouseclick coordinates are near or withing the bounds of the shown smiley... (mind you that the shown smiley will be shown from the selected coordinates + width and height)

And i think you can work out the rest.
Find examples for the stuff i told you and try to do soemthing on your own, never expect a working example, or else you won't know how to do anything...

Comment: paint is not the recommended method for performing custom painting. Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: May be so, but since this sounds like a homework questions, a basic, non-complex solution seemed good enough.
But i agree, your post is a lot better :)

Comment: That would be even more reason to demonstrate correct process :P

Comment: @DaMachk : +1, I liked the entire post, though -1, for recommending `paint()`. Since the basics of painting starts with overriding `paintComponent()`, as already answered in [Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html), just have a look at the very first problem and response to the same. And as referred by you, ___"First make sure you wipe everything from the Jpanel"___, simply call `super.paintComponent(g)` inside your `paintComponent()` method, that will do this trick too :-) `paint` method is used when one needs to change the state of `graphics` object.